# Syntax Error in simple bash script

Tags: bash, shell, syntax

Hello im new to bash scripting, i have a simple program which is not working for me. I assume its a syntactical error.

```
#!/bin/bash
#example1.sh
read Age
if ["$Age" -lt "18"]; then
    echo "You must go to school"
fi
```

When i input a 1 it says [1: command not found

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need spaces:

```
if [ "$Age" -lt "18" ]; then
```

(Summary: Bash syntax rules are appalling.)

Comment: `if test "$Age" -lt 18; then` is a much more reasonable syntax.

Comment: `if ((Age < 18)); then` is an even more reasonable syntax - the spaces are optional.

Comment: `[` is not part of the syntax of any Bourne shell.  `((` is part of the syntax for `bash`, but is not part of the syntax of many other shells.

Comment: As William Pursell states, `[` is not part of the syntax (nor is `[[`) they are commands. Commands must be surrounded by whitespace (or be preceded or followed by certain other characters such as `;` or `&`, etc.).

Comment: @DennisWilliamson: Granted.  But the fact that brackets are commands and not just part of the language grammar is what's appalling!

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
#example1.bash

read Age
if(($Age < 18)); then
echo "You must go to school"
fi
```

This code works when it is run in bash. Bash and sh are not completely the same.